# ¿Como se carga y ejecuta un programa [EXE] en memoria sobre Windows?

Tags: windows, exe

Se que los programas compilados para Windows nativos tienen un formato llamado [Portable executable (PE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) y que permite que el sistema operativo cargue el programa a la memoria.

[image: PE]

Pero me intriga el proceso mediante el cual se carga a la memoria y luego se ejecuta, o sea que sucede desde que doy click dentro del proceso explorer hasta que crean las ventanas de la propia aplicación llamando a winmain (esto se hace dentro del código del programa como en [la documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632598(v=vs.85).aspx)):

```
LONG APIENTRY MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

¿Que sucede entre estos dos eventos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El proceso es *relativamente sencillo* de explicar, pero no tanto **de llevar a cabo**.

Lo primero: las CPU tienen una serie de requisitos para poder **ejecutar** un trozo de código cualquiera: ciertos registros tienen que apuntar a direcciones de memoria válidas.

Adicionalmente, se han de cumplir las normas que imponga el Sistema Operativo de turno: cierto trozo de memoria solo puede ser accedido por cierto programa, y en cierto modo (lectura, escritura, ejecución).

El proceso básico de **ejecución** (que no de carga) consiste en preparar la memoria y los registros de la CPU para que cumplan los requisitos impuestos. Esto es llevado a cabo por el **Sistema Operativo**.

Para lo anterior, se consultan ciertos datos del archivo a ejecutar.

Una vez la memoria preparada, **se carga** el código en si, cada porción en la parte necesaria. Los *segmentos* de datos del programa se cargan en la zona de memoria dedicada para datos, los *segmentos* de código ejecutable en la zona de código, ...

Aquí, lo de *carga* puede ser engañoso. Mediante el proceso de *mapeo de archivos en memoria*, la antedicha *carga* se puede *posponer* hasta que la CPU no **necesite acceder realmente** a la zona de memoria en cuestión.

Una vez el código *cargado*, se procede a su *enlazado dinámico*. Es decir, se consulta el *segmento* del archivo que contiene el nombre de las librerías `.dll` que se necesitan. Algunas ya estarán cargadas (en zonas de memoria compartida, con ejecución para todo el mundo). Otras no, y será necesario repetir el proceso de *carga* para ellas (con sus peculiaridades; por ejemplo, las librerías no necesitan pila (*stack*).

Por fin, está todo *cargado* (o *mapeado en memoria). Ahora, hay que sobre-escribir los puntos del código del programa en los que se llama a ciertas funciones importadas, por las direcciones reales de las mismas.

Esto también es *engañoso*. Hay *mecanismos* para **no tener que recorrer toda la memoria**, usando unas zonas de memoria como *tablas intermedias*. El resultado final, no obstante, es el mismo: todas las llamadas a `.dll` apuntan al código deseado.

Ahora, ya sí, se puede comenzar la **ejecución** del programa, forzando a la CPU a crear un nuevo proceso, y usando para ello las zonas de memoria que con tanto *mimo* se han preparado.

Normalmente, la ejecución en si misma **no pasa directamente** a la función `WinMain`, o `main`, o lo que sea. Se llama primero a un trozo de código colocado por el compilador, que se encarga de realizar tareas de inicialización de los datos. En C++, por ejemplo, es este código *pre-main* el que se encarga de llamar a los constructores de instancias estáticas.

Ahora si; por fin, llamamos a nuestra `WinMain( )`.

**Una de las cosas** que podemos hacer dentro de `WinMain( )` es **registrar nuestra función de ventana**, que será usada por Windows para entregar los mensajes. Estos mensajes **se generan independientemente de nosotros**, la mayoría de ellos son *artificiales* (generados por el propio sistema). Pero eso ya es otro tema, y será contada en otra ocasión ...

Comment: Hay documentación oficial sobre este tema con la que puedas validar esta respuesta? :P

Comment: Ni idea. La mayoría de lo que te expongo lo recuerdo de un artículo hablando del *nuevo* (por aquella época) formato ejecutable `PE`, aparecido en la `Revista Microsoft Programadores`, allá por el 1990 y muchos (lo comparaban con el *viejo* `NE`, también de Windows). Otras cosas son de artículos técnicos sueltos, sobre los formatos `elf`, sobre como funciona un compilador, sobre memoria virtual en los Sistemas Operativos, ... en fin, que no te puedo dar una *Bibliografía* al respecto, aunque todo lo que leí la tenía O_O

Comment: @ArieCwHat Mira lo que he encontrado: [Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx).